# can bazel test if two rules are identical

Tags: bazel

I'd like to compare two rules to see whether or not they are identical (in particular, I'd like to be able to test a bazel target before and after a commit to see if it has changed)

Is there a way to accomplish this, perhaps with bazel query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `bazel query` with `--output=build` to have bazel print out the rule with everything expanded (e.g. macros evaluated, globs expanded, expressions evaluated, etc) before and after the change, and compare the results. See https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html#output-build for more information.